# php pdo csv file into db

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

My code is error free, but no data ever gets into the database. line 63 is where it should be doing the upload, but var_dump isn't much help.
php pdo 
My code is error free, but no data ever gets into the database. line 63 is where it should be doing the upload, but var_dump isn't much help.
php pdo

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
require_once('config.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Member Index</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/subnav.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];?></h1>
<a href="member-profile.php">My Profile</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<p>Welcome to the TPC Holdings SMS Campaign Builder</p>
<p></p>
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Nav Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<p></p>
<p>View your stats</p>
<p>Change your ip</p>
<p>Pay your bill</p>


  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input name="userfile" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>


<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname"; //Data Source Name = Mysql
$db = new PDO($dsn, $db_username, $db_password); //Connect to DB

$csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
        exit('File not found.');
if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {
        $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
        $q = "INSERT INTO customer_list (CSV) VALUES (contact_first, contact_last, sms_num)";
        //$q = "INSERT INTO customer_list (CSV) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        //var_dump($csv_file);
        $do = $db->prepare($q);
        $do->execute();
        var_dump('CSV');
        //var_dump($do);
}
fclose($handle);
exit( "Complete!" );
//exit( $sql );


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a mysql issue. I had the incorrect number of fields

(?,?,?)   to   (?,?,?,?,?,?)